# What are the permissible things in the Yoda dialect?

Tags: inversion, dialect

I've found such a quote of Yoda:

> “Powerful you have become, the dark side I sense in you.”

So, if I want to express my thoughts like him, will I be understood correctly by my clients if I, for instance, say:

> “The beer don't have we, peanuts we do.”

meaning "We don't have beer, only peanuts"?

Comment: Yoda's sentence would need a semicolon to be grammatically correct.  `“Powerful you have become; the dark side I sense in you.”`  That means they are essentially two independent clauses (that could be their own sentences) that are each inverted and put together into one sentence.  In inversion you want the verb at the end, so your sentence should probably be `Beer we don't have, only peanuts`.  Or maybe `beer we don't have, peanuts only`.

Comment: Is 'yoda dialect' English? I mean accepted English? :)

Comment: I don't know, but this question is hilarious as heck!  :-)

Comment: Standard English, Yoda-speak is not.  OSV word order, it uses.

Comment: Follow these links, you must. http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002173.html, http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002182.html. Good info, they have.

Comment: Entirely subjective this is.  _Peanuts do we have, but beer..._ [Shake you head here.] _...have we none._

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the English language.  It should be migrated to SciFi.SE.

Comment: This is a question about language, not science fiction; I'm not migrating it, I'm upvoting it. @Adam - that works especially well with a muppet-like grunt as you shake your head. To the O.P.: don't overuse this! This may get a laugh, but it's not the best dialect to use when you want to "be understood correctly" by clients.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a fictional language.

Comment: @TRomano - This question is about English, not a fictional language. Klingon is a fictional language; this question is about English as spoken by a fictional character. In my opinion, this is at worst a question about a fictional dialect.

Comment: @J.R. Baloney it is, anyway you slice it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yoda is putting the direct object at the beginning of the phrase.

Since I guess your original form is:

> We don't have beer, we have peanuts.

So in Yoda-speak it would be:

> Beer we don't have, peanuts we do (have).