# Using adjectives at the beginning of sentence

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I saw [this picture](http://www.edmoholics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/qr.jpg) on the internet. As you can see, there is a sentence written on the picture.

> United we are

The meaning is somehow clear. I think it means that "We are united". But i have 2 questions :

1. When do we use adjective at the beginning of a sentence? What's the usage?
2. Can we change the place of adjectives in order to fix the problems like "poetic meter"? If yes, how far can we go? Is there a rule?

Comment: It's actually the title of a musical work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_We_Are

Comment: Related: [What are the permissible things in the Yoda dialect?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46113/what-are-the-permissible-things-in-the-yoda-dialect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very often when one  departs from normal word order in English, the effect is to stress something.

Here, the subject complement *United* is stressed. So *United* receives stronger attention in the sentence *United we are*, since this varies from the normal, everyday, mundane, unremarkable *We are united*.

Another example:

*Down the long, dark, dust-filled road the cat slinked home.*

Here the prepositional phrase is moved to the front of the sentence; the effect again is to call attention to it.

Both of the examples above are actually "poetic"  in the sense that they depart from normal word order.

In poetry real, (<- see what I did there?), that is, in actual poetry, yes, authors move words around all the time, pulling them out  of normal word order. This can be to affect meter (either to stay in tune with it or to depart from it) or it can be, again, to call attention to whatever is not in normal word order.

In

> i thank You God for most this amazing
>   day

*most* is yanked out of its normal place between *this* and *day*, and the effect is astounding. Normally it would be *this most amazing day*.

Hear [the poem](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/features/audio/detail/76999) by E.E. Cummings.

Basically there are no rules in poetry, or other art.

Answer (score 1):

It is called fronting.

> Happy is the man who finally understands the meaning of life.

Usually the linking verb comes before the subject, but with pronouns, linking verbs come after the subject.

Here is the link. See 5, fronted plain adjectives.

http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2014/09/exploring-inversion-and-fronting.html