# Comparison grammar in The Lord of the Rings

Tags: word-order, adjective-phrases

I was reading *The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers* and I came across a sentence in which I don't fully understand its grammar.

> ..., and when they rose taller they seemed than mortal men.

I think I understand the meaning, but written in the grammar that I'm used to the sentence would be something like:

> ..., and when they rose, they seemed **taller** than mortal men.

I checked [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/comparatives-and-superlatives/comparison-adjectives-bigger-biggest-more-interesting) to see if I could find some kind of exception or explanation to this, but I couldn't find anything similar.

Maybe this is not common but...

- is it allowed?
- my copy of the book got this wrong?
- is it an *old* way of writing?
- did the author take a poetic license?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider just the main clause:

> Taller they seemed than mortal men.

The standard English way to write that would be "They seemed taller than mortal men."

English has a stricter word order than some other languages, but even it allows a little latitude for poetic effect, and moving a word to the end or the beginning is hand-waved when it highlights that word.  For example:

> Boldly they rode and well

(Tennyson)

> We were soldiers once and young.

(A.E. Housman)

Tolkien wanted a more archaic sound, without making the sentence unintelligible.

*Edit*: [This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/96586/using-adjectives-at-the-beginning-of-sentence) leads to [this useful article](http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2014/09/exploring-inversion-and-fronting.html).  This structure is apparently called "fronting".

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how important punctuation can be - put in a significant pause after the word `rose` (or insert a comma) and the whole sentance becomes far more poetic and lilting.

Still not common usage, but far more understandable.

Comment: Tolkien doesn't use a comma.

Comment: I know he doesn't. In his own head it was probably perfectly understandable, but on paper it isn't. No one is perfect - many authors think that they can break the rules of English with impunity, which is an entirely seperate argument.