# Why do you say "The Force is strong with him" instead of "in him"?

Tags: prepositions

I've just heard again the famous Star Wars line "[The Force is strong with him](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xpJhtfF9pk&feature=youtu.be&t=92)", and I've been struck by a question: why does it say that the Force is strong **with** him? Why is the preposition "with" used?

I'm not a native, but it sounds weird to me. Wouldn't it be better to say that the Force is strong **in** someone? In Episode VI, "Return of the Jedi", [Luke himself](https://youtu.be/MDYX_PgorRY?t=104) says that the Force is strong **in** his family. It's also said again in the [Official Teaser Trailer #2 of The Force Awakens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCc2v7izk8w&feature=youtu.be&t=33).

I am certainly influenced by the way it is said in my native language, Italian ("la Forza è potente **in** lui"), and also in German ("Die Macht ist stark **in** ihm"). But "with" just sounds terribly out of place to me.

Of course I realise that such a famous sentence can't *really* be wrong, but I still find it strange enough that I'd like to ask about it. Does this word choice make the sentence sound more solemn, maybe?

...Or is it just me, and there's really nothing special about it?

Comment: Also consider the phrase "[May the force be with you.](https://youtu.be/vSJNeXrCbE4)" I have a feeling that this is more of a [scifi.se] question than an English question, because it depends on your understanding of the nature of The Force.

Comment: There are many cases in English where more than one preposition works just fine. This is one of them.

Comment: See also "[What are the permissible things in the Yoda dialect?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46113)"

Comment: I suppose it was inevitable that someone would conclude that Yoda was a native English speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

George Lucas apparently intended "The Force" to be a kind of universal power that was not *inherent* to any individual, but rather something generated by all living things.  Certain talented individuals (like Jedi) can tap into the Force to use in various unique ways, but it is *with* them, not *in* them.

The mystical quality is reinforced by the oft-repeated

> May the Force be **with** you

which is similar to a religious benediction like

> May the blessing of God be **with** you and your family this holiday season

Yoda himself says:

> For my ally is the Force, and a powerful ally it is.

Which is to say, the Force is not something that goes *into* your body, but is *with* you all the time, if you can perceive it.

However, one of the lines in *Return of the Jedi* does say,

> The Force is strong **in** my family

so it's not entirely cut-and-dried.  In this case, it's likely Lucas is just mirroring the common expression when referring to about hereditary traits:

> Red hair **runs in** my family.

Later, he further complicates the issue with the whole *midichlorian* thing -- but most fans don't want to talk about that.